# Window.open function allowing to resize the widow after setting the resizable property as "0"

Tags: javascript, html, popup

When I try to call a URL as a pop-up window through JavaScript, after loading the pop-up window I am able to re-size the window by mouse dragging even after I set the `resizable` property as "0". Code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function poponload()
        {
            mywindow = window.open("factory.php?content=con1", "mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=0,width=300,height=300,resizable=0");
            mywindow.moveTo(150, 150);
        }
    </script>
```

Please clarify if I made any mistake in the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715201/how-can-we-disable-resizing-of-new-popup-window-in-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern day browsers can block window.open settings. There are no ways to override it unless you manually go to the user's computer and uncheck the checkbox for them.

Pop up windows should be avoided in this day and age. Modal layers placed on the page that are updated with Ajax or iframes can do the same thing and have no size, menubar, and  other restrictions placed on them.

Comment: ok, thanks for the useful information, i will check with Ajax and iframe.

Comment: Your last sentence seems to be to be contradictory. By its nature,  pop-up window is _not_ modal, and that is necessary in certain cloud-based applications. In our case, we explicitly state in the requirements that users _must_ allow pop-up windows, at least selectively.

Comment: @DavidA.Gray After 11 years I still stand by that statement.

Comment: Please feel free to stand away. I have two demonstrably practical use cases for pop-up windows, both involving the need to display windows alongside our commercial SaaS application. The first use case is displaying a video player alongside a list of events that occurred during the time when it was recorded, allowing users to click links in the list to advance the video to the corresponding point in time. Likewise, we display transcripts in the same manner so that they can be viewed alongside the activity list. Modal wouldn't cut it in either case.

Answer (score 4):

The following code opens a window with menu bar. The window is re-sizable and is having 350 pixels width and 250 pixels height.

```
window.open ("http://www.google.com","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
```

Comment: actually I don't want to re-size the pop-up window.

Comment: Use : window.resizeTo(width,height)

Comment: Could you tell me what type of browser you are using and the exact version

Comment: @Muse, he DOES NOT want to the window to be resizable.

Comment: @muse, Yes, I'm using Firefox5.0, meanwhile, the same code working perfectly in IE8 (means not allowing to re-sizing).

Answer (score 3):

Use: window.resizeTo(width,height)