# Same Window Resize On Click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a link inside of a page that brings up a floating window with a series of links.

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='window.open("http://mylink.html","ZenPad","width=150, height=900");' target='ZenPad'><img src=http://mygraphic.png></a>
```

The links on the page have (the coding in the below example) however when clicked, they appear in the same window that popped up, but the window remains at the size originally set at w150 and h900 unless you grab the side and drag it. Is there a way to have the window resize to fit the dimensions of the page the link is going to in the same window? An example of my coding below.

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='window.open("http://mylink.html","ZenPad","width=850, height=600");' target='ZenPad'><img src=http://myimg.png><br><font color="#34a6a7"></a>WHOCHAT</font><br><br>
```

edited to show my coding:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"><title>ReVo Links</title>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function newWindow(){
var windowWidth = 850;
var windowHeight = 600;
var xPos = (screen.width/2) - (windowWidth/2);
var yPos = (screen.height/2) - (windowHeight/2);
window.open("http://mywebpage.com","ZenPad","width=" 
+ windowWidth+",height="+windowHeight +",left="+xPos+",top="+yPos);
}
</script>
<body text="#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#000000">
<center><br>
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='newWindow()' target='_blank'><img src=http://mygraphiclink.png><br><font color="#34a6a7"></a>WHOCHAT</font><br><br>
```

(there are other links here that need to do the same thing just testing the first link to get it to work)

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is the matcing post for your question. [resize window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843249/javascript-window-open-function-allowing-to-resize-the-widow-after-setting-the)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the onclick for a `function` and set `target="_blank"` to open a new widow:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='newWindow()' target='_blank'><img src=http://myimg.png><br><font color="#34a6a7"></a>WHOCHAT</font><br><br>
```

And create the function to open new window, (this will be centered in screen and with personal size):

```
function newWindow(){
    var windowWidth = 850;
    var windowHeight = 600;
    var xPos = (screen.width/2) - (windowWidth/2);
    var yPos = (screen.height/2) - (windowHeight/2);
    window.open("http://mylink.html","ZenPad","width=" 
    + windowWidth+",height="+windowHeight +",left="+xPos+",top="+yPos);
}
```

Comment: thank you Jordi I input that coding and it goes to the correct link however the window doesn't resize to the new size

Comment: I'm not seeing an error, no. It loads just doesn't resize the window will update my code above in case I'm missing something.

Comment: its saying my onclick event for onclick='newWindow() is undefined somehow.