# I don't want pop up window to be resizable

Tags: html, css, browser

I have a popup window which appears after clicking on a button. I don't want the pop up window though to be resizeable. I tried using in css `resize:none` and `resizable:none` but this does not work for all browsers.

Is there a css element that can be used so that pop window can not resizable in all browsers, or is there a lot of different ressizeable related css elements so that I can use them so eventually all pop up windows are not resizable in all broswers?

I know where to put the css elements, in the window.open function, I just want to know other css ways that can make pop up windows not resizable for all browsers

Browsers using (all latest browsers): IE, Firefox, Google Chrome, safari and Opera

Comment: This is not good practice. It is the user who should decide if they want to re-size the window or not. Don't be such a control freak :)

Comment: How about not using pop-ups? Not to mention that people dislike them, many browsers (on phones, tablets) may even not support them.

Comment: Hey, BruceyBandit. Any chance you're ready now, 5 years and 11 months later, to mark my answer as *the* answer :-)?

Answer (score 11):

You can't do this with CSS - you need to pass the `resizable` parameter to your `window.open()` function. If you're using an `anchor` with the `target` attribute, you need to use JavaScript instead.

**JS Example**

```
window.open ("http://URL","mywin","menubar=1,resizable=0,width=350,height=250");
```

**JS & HTML Example**

```
<a href="#"
  onclick="window.open ('http://URL','mywin','resizable=0,width=350,height=250')">Open</a>
```

**Additional Resources**

Take a look at the `window.open` docs on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

According to MDN, Firefox will not support the resizable attribute:

> **resizable**
>
> If this feature is set to yes, the new secondary window
> will be resizable. Note: Starting with version 1.4, Mozilla-based
> browsers have a window resizing grippy at the right end of the status
> bar, this ensures that users can resize the browser window even if the
> web author requested this secondary window to be non-resizable. In
> such case, the maximize/restore icon in the window's titlebar will be
> disabled and the window's borders won't allow resizing but the window
> will still be resizable via that grippy in the status bar.
>
> Starting
> with Firefox 3, secondary windows are always resizable ( bug [177838](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=177838) )

Comment: I know that but what I am saying is resizable and resize does not work on all browsers

Comment: Yes I am, I don't mean I am using css to resize the pop up window, it is on javascript in the window.open function, what I am asking is that are there other css elements to resize pop up windows instead of resizable or resize

Comment: Chrome is also on board with this user friendly option.

Comment: does not works in chrome `Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqib, this is the only convention provided by JS to prevent window resizing. Having said that, it's up to the browser whether said convention is allowed/accepted. Google has decided that this makes for an unfriendly interface for users and ignores the request. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480252/make-window-not-resizable-in-chrome/15481333 for further info.

Comment: @JamesHill I mentioned it to notify viewers so they can get aware the hidden problems before publishing their apps.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox doesn't support this.

have a look here:

[how can we disable resizing of new popup window in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715201/how-can-we-disable-resizing-of-new-popup-window-in-firefox)

futher more, it's a bad idea to make it not-resizeable.  what if your users are visually impaired have have there settings to have large fonts?

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never. Got this working:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const popup = window;
  console.log(popup);
  popup.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    popup.resizeTo(306, 512);
  })
});
```