# Make window not resizable in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have some JavaScript that I use to make a window not resizable, something along the lines of:

```
window.open(URL, id, "resizable=no");
```

This works in most browsers but it appears to not be supported in Chrome. I have considered using JavaScript to watch for a re-size and set it back, but this is not ideal. Does anyone have any other suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a known issue they have no plan on fixing: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=185425

Comment: Forcing window/tab sizes on users is quite pointless these days. Most modern browsers ignore stuff that might patronize the user, or at least have options to disable such features.

Comment: OK thanks guys those links were useful, I think I will look at if it really does not to be a fixed size.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is old school javascript. Modern browsers tend to not allow this because it is seen as a user unfriendly limitation.

Answer (score 14):

This was easy to do with the old javascript with popups and a "resizable = 0" parameter a while ago, but current browsers do not allow this because they killed user's freedom. This initiative started with firefox and chrome followed him, probably the solution for this case is creating an chrome extension and that only works for chrome, but it seems a madness.

> After some discussions, the consensus seems to be that window.open()
>   should not be modified to parse "resizeable", at least at this time.
>   The change would require modifications to Webkit, and the behavior
>   would be inconsistent with Firefox and existing Webkit browsers.

[see more here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=185425)

> We always allow a window to be resized, which is consistent with
>   Firefox.

[see more here](https://docs.google.com/document/edit?id=14nBjW6gHJW0kk44o8Z8vfDSnDi0ZT1sUU74Zc5wmwIQ&hl=en&authkey=CKT6-O8I#)

Comment: +1 - Both Chrome and FF (See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216208/i-dont-want-pop-up-window-to-be-resizable#answer-8216251 ) are giving users the control over their browser windows. It's a good thing.