# open a new window without address bar

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for HTML/JavaScript code to open a new window with only a "close" option; users should not able to maximize or minimize the window. This is similar to the window which we get in Internet Explorer in `Tools -> About Internet Explorer`.

Below is the code which I tried; however, I can increase/decrease the width of the window using mouse or by using the maximize/minimize buttons. How can I disable those options?

```
<SCRIPT>
<!--
window.open ('titlepage.html', 'newwindow', config='height=100,width=400, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,location=no, directories=no, status=no')
-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Haven't seen the `LANGUAGE` attribute in a while, where'd you get that from, a book published sometime in the last millennium?

Answer (score 5):

I'll risk answering this for you, though it's my first time answering so go easy on me (I would comment but my reputation isn't high enough).

this feature is supported only on IE, i.e. for example in Chrome and Firefox the user can still resize the window even with 'resizable=no'. If you do a search on SO you'll find that this has been asked many times before, for example.
[Make window not resizable in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480252/make-window-not-resizable-in-chrome)

therefore to do what you're wanting to do I would probably use an external script, such as Popup.js, which supports ajax.

as a footnote, you may want to refer to the W3 guide on window.open:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp