# Cross Browser: How to restrict refresh, Resizable in Window.showmodal Dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, modal-dialog

I am Using "window.showmodal" for open modal window.

```
window.showModalDialog('/servlet/ZServlet?api=loadJobBoardDetails&rand='+myRandom,obj,"dialogHeight: 600px; dialogWidth: 1100px; dialogTop: px; dialogLeft: px; center: Yes; help: No; resizable: No; status: No; scroll: yes;");
```

In I.E, this modal works as non-Draggable and non- resizable window. and also we could not refresh the window using f5 or using mouse, but in Cross Browser ( Firefox, Chrmo, Safari ), above the features are not working.

Any Other way to do the same. Any Help ??

Comment: It is not possible to specify a Firefox or Chrome window as non-resizable, as the developers consider that to be very user-unfriendly. I imagine the same is true for Safari and the other features you mention, but I don't know that for a fact. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216208/i-dont-want-pop-up-window-to-be-resizable for more details.