# How to make the html page unresizable?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to open a web page and make it unresizable. I used these c# code but it is still resizable. How is it possible? thanks?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
  string url = "Popup.aspx";
  string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=no');";
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can we disable resizing of new popup window in firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715201/how-can-we-disable-resizing-of-new-popup-window-in-firefox)