# How to customize the title of my browser window

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I want to customize the display of my html, using `window.open()`. I wrote the code below, and got the output as per the screen shot attached.

My points are:

1. I found the window to be `resizable` though i used `resizable=no`
2. how to hide the `bar title`
3. How to add my customs title to the form/page, I want to replace the `untitled` by `report`:

`var report = window.open('', '_blank', 'title="Report",toolbar=0, top=500,left=500, width=200,height=100,resizable=no,scrollbars=no, menubar=no, location=no, status=no');`

```
report.document.body.innerHTML = text;
```

[image]

Comment: If @Will answer doesnt work for some reason try adding title tag inside innerHTML( your text)

Comment: you can't hide the address bar for security (anti-spoofing) reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a title to appear in the new window just set the `title` tag in your `text` inside the `<head>`.

```
<title>Title you want</title>
```

Example:

```
var report = window.open('', '_blank', 'title="Report",toolbar=0, top=500,left=500, width=200,height=100,resizable=no,scrollbars=no, menubar=no, location=no, status=no');
report.document.write("<html><head><title>TEST</title></head></html>");
```

Notice that I used `document.write()`.

Also, in modern browser is not permitted to hide the url bar, you can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16603908/4266836).

The resize option has also a bug. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1715220/4266836) answer about disabling resize of new windows.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @Will and @GerardCuadras

Both answers are workable, so not sure which to accept as correct one, i voted up for both of them.

```
report.document.title = 'My customs Report';
report.document.body.innerHTML = text;
```

or

```
report.document.body.innerHTML = '<title>My customs Report</title>';
report.document.body.innerHTML += text;
```

Comment: Note that mine, answer all points of your question. The @Will one doesn't explain anything and that's not a good practice.

Comment: @GerardCuadras thanks a lot, your answer had been accepted as the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

```
var report = window.open('', '_blank', 'title="Report",toolbar=0, top=500,left=500, width=200,height=100,resizable=no,scrollbars=no, menubar=no, location=no, status=no');
report.document.body.innerHTML = text;

**report.document.title = 'custom one';**
```